# Why would someone use an article before a name

Tags: article

I was being introduced to my colleagues by my boss and I noticed the use of  the article die before my name. Why would someone call a proper name out with an article attached??

Comment: Must have been in the South? This would not happen in, say, Hamburg. :-)

Comment: Yeah. i was living in kiel all this while and moved to the south recently.

Comment: Also in Austria -> *'Das hat doch die Susi gestern erzählt...'*

Comment: Maybe this is a thing of the South of Germany . If you say "die Merkel, der Schröder, der Beckenbauer or die Brigit Bardot" this refers to personalities everybody knows. But the definite article can be used before any proper name of a person: der Peter, die Maria. It always means the person spoken to knows who we are talking about. This is a thing of very colloquial language. At school Bavarian children are taught, to use person names without definite article. They do so at school, at home they use der Peter, die Maria.

Comment: i am also living in bavaria at the moment..